# How to pass component to props using React TypeScript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I am learning React with TypeScript. And I ran into such a problem.
I have a parent component:

```
import React from 'react';
import TestPropsComponent from './TestPropsComponent';
    
 const SomeTable: React.FC= () => {
   return (
     <table>
      <caption>Some Table</caption>
       <tr>
         <th>SomeData1</th>
          <th>SomeData2</th>
          <th>SomeData3</th>
       </tr>
       <tr><td>34,5</td><td>3,5</td><td>36</td></tr>
       <tr><td>35,5</td><td>4</td><td>36⅔</td></tr>
       <tr><td>36</td><td>4,5</td><td>37⅓</td></tr>
     </table>
   );
  }

const App: React.FC = () => {

return (
   <TestPropsComponent someTable={SomeTable}/>
 )
}

export default App;
```

how can I pass the SomeTable component to TestPropsComponent? 
i created an interface

```
export interface ITestPropsComponent {
    someTable: React.ComponentType
}
```

the child component looks like this

```
import React from 'react';
import { ITestPropsComponent } from './interface/ITestPropsComponent';


const TestPropsComponent: React.FC<ITestPropsComponent> = ({someTable}) => {
 return (
     {someTable}
 )

}

export default TestPropsComponent
```

but nothing is rendered and an error is displayed

```
The type "({someTable}: PropsWithChildren <ITestPropsComponent>) => {someTable: ComponentType <{}>;}" cannot be assigned to the type "FC <ITestPropsComponent>".
  The type "{someTable: ComponentType <{}>;}" is missing the following properties from the type "ReactElement <any, any>": type, props, key
```

Please tell me the best practice for such a case

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your code, that `someTable` in your `TestPropsComponent` is a `Component` not a simple node, so you have to invoke it:

```
const TestPropsComponent: FC<ITestPropsComponent> = ({ someTable: SomeTable }) => {
    return <SomeTable />;
}
```

[Full example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecBiAwtoROBAHZIUwAqAnmEnAL5wBmUZcA5FKhh4BuAFAi0lAM7wAymSS0UAIwA2SAFwFCcALxwAFAEpdAPlwi4luPxgBXKBQMWrLgDwxlak85e%204rtBQwGGBKEzkQZkVVJFcAekDg0IpvPz93KFS07PcAC3D5ABEUDwBGeJh8n2zfPILI4o8AJgqqmrS6iKRGlABmVqz2iszqnJhM9wATE16AFkwAVgrpqZnF5ZNV3oA2DeHBmozNmGnehfW4k%20Pp2b2rncAVQj3LkfbLI63dy5Wr%20aXv64zADsgGVCZ7jA5uS6eJAHQyiFhiJAAD0gsDgwBoSCg7HQzAAkrQkNIAApcMCSUjkKg0cwuSTyaJqTRUyA0uiMJAiRHiKTwImk8mUshs6gwTREVyE4kwMkQCmsyhisx6fR4BmRJkaOBdLWsYw6Mw4ao2eyOfSjKyuXUwuBxOHcsQSCgMtQAOhUEAA5vpXALZULFey4BqFDCdDgbTE2PbDEA)

Comment: Thank you very much! Everything works. And if, for example, the passed component contains props?

Comment: `ComponentType` is generic, you can specify the props of the element in the interface `someTable: ComponentType<TableProps>`.